# Too many indices for array 2

Tags: python

I'm writing this code in Python 2.7.13 to solve this problem : 
visit https://projecteuler.net/problem=11

This is my code :

```
from numpy import * 
from tab import tab
def euler011(tab):
   dim = len(tab)
   grid = array(tab)
   r, r3 = range(dim), range(dim-3)
   m1 = max(prod(grid[i,j:j+4]) for i in r for j in r3)
   m2 = max(prod(grid[i:i+4,j]) for i in r3 for j in r)
   m3 = max(prod(diag(grid[i:i+4,j:j+4])) for i in r3 for j in r3)
   m4 = max(prod(diag(grid[i:i+4,j+4:j:-1])) for i in r3 for j in r3)
   return max(m1,m2,m3,m4)
print(euler011(tab))
```

When I run this code I get a message error:

```
IndexError: Too many indices for array
```

Comment: Where you saw the use of `,` inside array indexing?

Comment: You can index numpy arrays like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have problem with import tab, when I initiate array by myself i don't get any errors however answer is wrong.

```
from numpy import *

tab = """\
08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48\
"""
tab = array([array(i.split(), dtype=int) for i in tab.splitlines()])

def euler011(tab):
   dim = len(tab)
   grid = array(tab)
   r, r3 = range(dim), range(dim-3)
   m1 = max(prod(grid[i,j:j+4]) for i in r for j in r3)
   m2 = max(prod(grid[i:i+4,j]) for i in r3 for j in r)
   m3 = max(prod(diag(grid[i:i+4,j:j+4])) for i in r3 for j in r3)
   m4 = max(prod(diag(grid[i:i+4,j+4:j:-1])) for i in r3 for j in r3)
   return max(m1,m2,m3,m4)
print(euler011(tab)) # -> 70600674
```

Using your method (importing tab), tab.py should look like this:

```
tab=[[8, 2, 22, 97, 38, 15, 0, 40, 0, 75, 4, 5, 7, 78, 52, 12, 50, 77, 91, 8], [49, 49, 99, 40, 17, 81, 18, 57, 60, 87, 17, 40, 98, 43, 69, 48, 4, 56, 62, 0], [81, 49, 31, 73, 55, 79, 14, 29, 93, 71, 40, 67, 53, 88, 30, 3, 49, 13, 36, 65], [52, 70, 95, 23, 4, 60, 11, 42, 69, 24, 68, 56, 1, 32, 56, 71, 37, 2, 36, 91], [22, 31, 16, 71, 51, 67, 63, 89, 41, 92, 36, 54, 22, 40, 40, 28, 66, 33, 13, 80], [24, 47, 32, 60, 99, 3, 45, 2, 44, 75, 33, 53, 78, 36, 84, 20, 35, 17, 12, 50], [32, 98, 81, 28, 64, 23, 67, 10, 26, 38, 40, 67, 59, 54, 70, 66, 18, 38, 64, 70], [67, 26, 20, 68, 2, 62, 12, 20, 95, 63, 94, 39, 63, 8, 40, 91, 66, 49, 94, 21], [24, 55, 58, 5, 66, 73, 99, 26, 97, 17, 78, 78, 96, 83, 14, 88, 34, 89, 63, 72], [21, 36, 23, 9, 75, 0, 76, 44, 20, 45, 35, 14, 0, 61, 33, 97, 34, 31, 33, 95], [78, 17, 53, 28, 22, 75, 31, 67, 15, 94, 3, 80, 4, 62, 16, 14, 9, 53, 56, 92], [16, 39, 5, 42, 96, 35, 31, 47, 55, 58, 88, 24, 0, 17, 54, 24, 36, 29, 85, 57], [86, 56, 0, 48, 35, 71, 89, 7, 5, 44, 44, 37, 44, 60, 21, 58, 51, 54, 17, 58], [19, 80, 81, 68, 5, 94, 47, 69, 28, 73, 92, 13, 86, 52, 17, 77, 4, 89, 55, 40], [4, 52, 8, 83, 97, 35, 99, 16, 7, 97, 57, 32, 16, 26, 26, 79, 33, 27, 98, 66], [88, 36, 68, 87, 57, 62, 20, 72, 3, 46, 33, 67, 46, 55, 12, 32, 63, 93, 53, 69], [4, 42, 16, 73, 38, 25, 39, 11, 24, 94, 72, 18, 8, 46, 29, 32, 40, 62, 76, 36], [20, 69, 36, 41, 72, 30, 23, 88, 34, 62, 99, 69, 82, 67, 59, 85, 74, 4, 36, 16], [20, 73, 35, 29, 78, 31, 90, 1, 74, 31, 49, 71, 48, 86, 81, 16, 23, 57, 5, 54], [1, 70, 54, 71, 83, 51, 54, 69, 16, 92, 33, 48, 61, 43, 52, 1, 89, 19, 67, 48]]
```

Comment: I want to to  know exactly  the problem due to import tab

Comment: In fact I created a file called tab.py , it contains:

Comment: tab=[[8,2,22,97,38,15,0,40,0,75,4,5,7,78,52,12,50,77,91,8],
[49,49,99,40,17,81,18,57,60,87,17,40,98,43,69,48,4,56,62,0],
[81,49,31,73,55,79,14,29,93,71,40,67,53,88,30,3,49,13,36,65],
[52,70,95,23,4,60,11,42,69,24,68,56,1,1,32,56,71,37,2,36,91],
[22,31,16,71,51,67,63,89,41,92,36,54,22,40,40,28,66,33,13,80],
[24,47,32,60,99,3,45,2,44,75,33,53,78,36,84,20,35,17,12,50],
[32,98,81,28,64,23,67,10,26,38,40,67,59,54,70,66,18,38,64,70],
[67,26,20,68,2,62,12,20,95,63,94,39,63,8,40,91,66,49,94,21],
[24,55,58,5,66,73,99,26,97,17,78,78,96,83,14,88,34,89,63,72]]

Comment: ( It 's not the full tab of course because it cannot be written fully in the comment

Comment: You haven't copied whole elements for tab, when I did it worked, I'm adding correct tab.py to my answer.

Comment: In fact,  my file contains the same answer ( tab.py ) that you have written, however

Comment: I get it and it works, My question is: is there a difference between writing the tab as you did in a single line or writing it as I did ( in matrix form)?

Comment: I did it in such way to make sure I provide here all code that was needed to execute my code, your way is for sure more clear but there's not much difference.